# How to delete custom emoji from server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How do I delete custom emojis from my Discord Server?
I want to temporarily create an emoji by adding it to the server, sending it to a specific channel and then deleting it

```js
const emoji = message.guild.emojis.create("link", "name")
message.channel.send(emoji)
//Now deleting it
```

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Emoji.delete()`. Note that I don't know if your discord client will be able to show the image of a deleted emoji.

```js
const emoji = message.guild.emojis.create("link", "name")
message.channel.send(emoji)
//Now deleting it
emoji.delete();
```